# How to make rounded screen corner web page like in an Android smartphone?

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to make a rounded screen corner on a web page like in an Android smartphone.

For example: https://img.gadgethacks.com/img/73/43/63501814144009/0/get-rounded-screen-corners-your-samsung-galaxy-s3-other-android-device.w1456.jpg

I have searched for various tutorials on the internet but have not found the results.

Please help. _/_

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use CSS. I presume you're looking for "border-radius" property. Here is how it's written as well as a link to where you can find more information.

```
#example1 {
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

#example2 {
  border: 2px solid red;
  border-radius: 50px 20px;
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

Comment: The CSS property "border-radius" I already know.

What I'm looking for is, how to make a rounded corner on the edge of a web page, not on an element.

For example on Android smart phones. Please see an example: https://img.gadgethacks.com/img/73/43/63501814144009/0/get-rounded-screen-corners-your-samsung-galaxy-s3-other-android-device.w1456.jpg

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

To create this kind of design, I would make two different elements.
One element underneath that is black and is fixed and stretched up and down and left to right.
On top, I would put my "classic" window with border-radius.

```html
<body>
<div></div>

<div>
    <header></header>
</div>
</body>
```

... and design :

```css
body > div:first-of-type {
    position         : fixed;
    top              : 0;
    left             : 0;
    bottom           : 0;
    right            : 0;
    z-index          : -1;
    background-color : black;
}

body > div:nth-of-type(2) {
    background-color : white;
    position         : fixed;
    top              : 0;
    left             : 0;
    bottom           : 0;
    right            : 0;
    z-index          : 1;
    border-radius    : 25px;
}

body > div:nth-of-type(2) > header {
    height        : 25vh;
    background    : linear-gradient(to bottom, #54c3ff, #ddf7ff);
    border-radius : 25px 25px 0 0;
}
```